# Blocking user submissions for 24 hours, and showing how many hours left on the block

Tags: php, mysql

In the code below, `datesubmitted` is a timestamp.  If a given `$uid` has submitted within 24 hours, I want them to not be able to submit, and see a message that shows how many hours until they can submit again.

The code below seems to work for at least the first few hours (it shows 24 during the first hour, then 23 during the 2nd hour).  But when I checked today and expected to see 4-6 hours left on the message, the message wasn't there at all.

Is there something wrong with my code?

```
$queryuidcount = "select loginid from submission where TO_DAYS(datesubmitted) = TO_DAYS(NOW()) AND loginid = '$uid'"; 
$uidresult = mysql_query($queryuidcount);

if (mysql_num_rows($uidresult) >= 1) {
    $queryuidhours = "select loginid, 24 - HOUR(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), datesubmitted)) as hours from submission where loginid = '$uid' ORDER BY hours DESC"; 
    $hourresult = mysql_query($queryuidhours);
    $hourcount = 1;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($hourresult)) {
        echo '<div class="submittitle">You will not be able to submit again for '.$row["hours"].' hours.</div>';
        break;
        $hourcount++;
    }
    mysql_free_result($hourresult);
} else {
```

Comment: FYI, you are likely wide open to SQL injection, depending on how you populate `$uid`.  You should escape all variables you intend to use in queries.  Better yet, use prepared queries with PDO.

Comment: @ Brad, $uid is a session variable.  Do I still need to run that through mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: that depends on how you are populating the session variable then.  If you force it to be an `int`, then you should be fine.  As a rule, I escape everything when using it in the query, just so there is nothing to worry about, should some bad data end up in that variable.  Escaping can't hurt.

Answer (score 2):

What's the first SQL query for? Once midnight has passed, it will return nothing, even if a submission happened just minutes before midnight.

(And what's up with the `while` loop that is broken out of unconditionally in the middle of the first iteration?)

Also also: your queries look unnecessarily demanding on the database. It would probably be much more efficient if you start by computing a cut-off timestamp as "24 hours ago" and then simply select rows that are newer than that. Once you get a row back (if you do), you can compute how long time is left on the PHP side instead. (Or even just retrieve the most recent submission time and then do the entire embargo calculation outside the database).

Comment: @ Henning.  Okay, thanks.  How could I make that 24 hour time stamp?

Comment: Take the current time and subtract 24 hours?

Comment: No, on the PHP side, and then feed it to SQL as a query parameter.

Comment: @ Henning, I won't worry about taxing my database.  I think your insight about the first query returning nothing after midnight was the all info I needed.